# importerror: no module named html.parser

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Eclipse + python 2.7
when i use from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, an error occur
The error list is following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\SDK\SampleTest\FileSearch\src\logic\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "D:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry
  File "D:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 279, in <module>
    from . import _htmlparser
  File "D:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_htmlparser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from html.parser import HTMLParser
ImportError: No module named html.parser
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#problems-after-installation) documentation is pretty clear about it:

> If you get the ImportError “No module named html.parser”, your problem
>   is that you’re running the Python 3 version of the code under Python
>   2.

Answer (score 1):

@alecxe's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23555935/1923016) didn't help in my case. For me, it turned out that I had accidentally downloaded an earlier version of BeautifulSoup either because I was using pip (rather than **pip3**) or because the [link](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup) on crummy.com (aptly named) pointed me to a site directory of an old version of BeautifulSoup that Python3 doesn't support anymore... hence the import error.

If you are in my situation: you'll find that the error message points you to a directory in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/.../lib/site-packages`. Remove all folders related to **bs4** and then follow the same instructions for your `.tar.gz` found in the link on crummy.com (above) (`python[X] setup.py install`), but this time, get your stinking *latest* tarball from https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/