# Error using pelican-quickstart "No module named html_parser"

Tags: python, pelican

I decided to give `pelican` a try, but when I run `pelican-quickstart`, I get the following dialog:

```
$ pelican-quickstart
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pelican-quickstart", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pelican==3.4.0', 'console_scripts', 'pelican-quickstart')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 357, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2394, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2108, in load
entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pelican-3.4.0-py2.7.egg/pelican/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
from pelican.generators import (ArticlesGenerator, PagesGenerator,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pelican-3.4.0-py2.7.egg/pelican/generators.py", line 23, in <module>
from pelican.readers import Readers
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pelican-3.4.0-py2.7.egg/pelican/readers.py", line 24, in <module>
from six.moves.html_parser import HTMLParser
ImportError: No module named html_parser `
```

There was a similar error message in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555906/importerror-no-module-named-html-parser), and since I'm running Python 2.7.6 on OS X 10.10 (Yosemite), there may be a similar issue.

What's the best way to address this?

Comment: The answer in the post you linked says that the error occurs when you "[run] the Python 3 version of the code under Python 2."

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You may need to install six.

if you're using pip, try

```
pip install six
```

and then restart pelican-quickstart

Comment: what is your `pip freeze` output ?

You can try to run a python console and then type `import six`

Comment: $ pip freeze
Jinja2==2.7.3
Markdown==2.5.1
MarkupSafe==0.23
Pygments==2.0rc1
Twisted==13.2.0
Unidecode==0.04.16
altgraph==0.10.2
argparse==1.2.1
bdist-mpkg==0.5.0
blinker==1.3
bonjour-py==0.3
docutils==0.12
feedgenerator==1.7
macholib==1.5.1
matplotlib==1.3.1
modulegraph==0.10.4
numpy==1.8.0rc1
pelican==3.4.0
py2app==0.7.3

Comment: pyOpenSSL==0.13.1
pyobjc-core==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Accounts==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Automator==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreData==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreText==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-EventKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents==2.5.1

Comment: pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Message==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PubSub==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-QTKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Quartz==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Social==2.5.1

Comment: pyobjc-framework-SyncServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-WebKit==2.5.1
pyparsing==2.0.1
python-dateutil==1.5
pytz==2013.7
scipy==0.13.0b1
six==1.8.0
stevedore==1.0.0
virtualenv==1.11.6
virtualenv-clone==0.2.5
virtualenvwrapper==4.3.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
xattr==0.6.4
zope.interface==4.1.1

Comment: So six is installed. Are you in a virtual env ? If not, you should try to work in a virtual env. It is strange you have so much libraries installed.

Comment: Have you try to run a python console and then type import six?

Comment: I am not in an virtual env - still a Python novice. Running `import six` in the Python console seems to work, but still can't figure out how to resolve my original issue. Thanks for your help (and patience) with this!

Comment: Using virtualenv is pretty simple. https://blog.dbrgn.ch/2012/9/18/virtualenv-quickstart/

Comment: this is not six-related problem

Answer (score 10):

Reinstall Pelican doesn't help me, so I made a little fix in pelican

Modifications were made in following file

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pelican/readers.py
```

at line 24 place

```
from six.moves import html_parser
```

instead of

```
from six.moves.html_parser import HTMLParser
```

and at line 299

```
    class _HTMLParser(html_parser.HTMLParser):
```

instead of

```
    class _HTMLParser(HTMLParser):
```

Modification actual for pelican 3.6.0, but seems to applicable for other version if search for this lines in readers.py file. This is just quick workaround, hope this problem will be solved at pelican's side.

Answer (score 5):

This error seems to come from Python 2.7.6 on OSX.  When I install python via Homebrew and reinstall this module I got rid of this error.

```
$ pip uninstall pelican
$ brew install python
$ which python # should show /usr/local/bin/python
$ python -V # should show Python 2.7.8
$ pip install pelican
```

Comment: I have a repro with 2.7.10.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you've probably encountered with **version conflict problem** in module `six`.

Try `sudo pip install virtualenv` to create an isolate python environment.

**start**

1. create your pelican path `mkdir /path/to/pelican`
2. go to `/path/to/pelican` and create an isolate python environment with `virtualenv venv`
3. activate virtualenv `source venv/bin/activate`
4. install pelican under the venv(without sudo!) `pip install pelican markdown`

**done**

and now you are free to any problem mentioned above. all the dependencies in the venv are isolated from the global environment.

To quit the venv, type `deactivate`

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same error message.

`six` was also already installed, but an old version (1.4.1)

`pip install six --upgrade`

Installed six 1.10.0, which made `pelican-quickstart` finally work :)