# El Capitan Broke Pelican

Tags: python, python-2.7, osx-elcapitan, pelican

I updated to El Capitan a few days ago, and, Pelican hasn't worked ever since. I asked a question on SO already about disabling SIP (rootless) thinking that it was the cause of the problem; but the answers on that question said they didn't think SIP was the culprint.

So does the Pelican community have any thoughts? `make devserver` yields the following result:

```
Last login: Wed Dec 23 22:30:30 on ttys003
Mischas-MacBook-Pro:~ mischa$ pwd
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Home
Mischas-MacBook-Pro:~ mischa$ cd /Volumes/SSD/users/mischa/Dropbox/website
Mischas-MacBook-Pro:website mischa$ ls
Makefile        pelican.pid     srv.pid
content         pelicanconf.py      subdirectory.txt
develop_server.sh   pelicanconf.pyc     themes
fabfile.py      publishconf.py
output          publishconf.pyc
Mischas-MacBook-Pro:website mischa$ make devserver
/Users/mischa/Dropbox/website/develop_server.sh restart
Stale PID, deleting
Stale PID, deleting
Starting up Pelican and HTTP server
/usr/bin/python: No module named html_parser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pelican", line 7, in <module>
    from pelican import main
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pelican/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pelican.generators import (ArticlesGenerator, PagesGenerator,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pelican/generators.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pelican.readers import Readers
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pelican/readers.py", line 24, in <module>
    from six.moves.html_parser import HTMLParser
ImportError: No module named html_parser
Pelican didn't start. Is the Pelican package installed?
make: *** [devserver] Error 1
Mischas-MacBook-Pro:website mischa$
```

I'm running **Mac OSX 10.11.2, Python 2.7.10, Pelican 3.6.3**

I tried all three of the solutions suggested here: [Error using pelican-quickstart "No module named html_parser"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508606/error-using-pelican-quickstart-no-module-named-html-parser?rq=1) and no luck so far.

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you read https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/issues/1674? Are you using a virtualenv? Which version of `six` is your code seeing?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hmm, I hadn't seen that. I am indeed using an old version of six 1.4.1; I'll try and set everything up in a virtualenv now and see if that fixes it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Installed a virtual env, doesn't seem to have fixed it, and is now running the most up to date version of six I believe. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried using Python 3?

Comment: A friend with a supreme command of python managed to diagnose the problem and fix it. His summary:

> I think it was kind of a mess of the Mac OS X default Python path    (/Library/Python) v.s. Brew's paths, and some things were running off one path and some the other. So I just removed the existing pelican and six in the OSX paths and made sure everything is running off the brew path

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the hint of @jonrsharpe helped to solve it. I had to start with `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 XXX`.